# HasMany association coming wrong with "raw" and "nest" as true

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Maybe it is a bug in sequelize, I just opened an issue there.

[click here to see the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RLKo.png)

Comment: Please show both parts of code as formatted pieces of code right in your post

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement. Good luck 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `raw` option makes Sequelize to return plain query results without grouping them (that's why it's called "raw"). So that means that if you have two child records for each main record then you'll end up with `N*2` objects returned by Sequelize.
If you wish to get plain objects instead of Sequelize model instances just call `get({ plain: true})` for each of model instances:

```js
const cart = await Cart.findOne({
...
})
const plainCart = cart.get({ plain: true})
```

Comment: It didn't work as expected, the only way I could manage what I wanted was putting this: "JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cart))", thank you

Comment: `get({ plain: true})` totally works, I use it every day. It returns plain JS object with all fields indicated in `attributes` and all linked associated models as object props if you used `include` option.

Comment: if I put "plain" in every include probably would work, but I preferred use the this little hacky

Comment: You need to call `get({ plain: true})` only on top level model instances you got from Sequelize,